# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'cache' not found - PHP

Tags: php, xampp

I've just started a new job where the last developer had left without leaving any documentation on the existing applications. They have an e-commerce app written with PHP that I'm trying to get a dev environment running for.

I scp'd a copy of the production directory onto my local machine and tried running it with a XAMPP server Apache/MYySQL. The project works fine on production. The stack trace leads to what appears to be a missing "cache" class. If this was the case, how is it running on production?

Hoping this is something you PHP guys may have seen before, thanks.

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'cache' not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\paige\production\rentals\cart\phplib\category.php:6 Stack 
trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\paige\production\rentals\cart\phplib\blocks.php(4): 
include_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\paige\production\rentals\cart.php(4): 
include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\paige\production\rentals\cart\phplib\category.php on line 6
```

This is line 1-10 in category.php

```
 <?php

include_once __DIR__.'/../../config/globals.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../../phplib/conn.old.php';

if (!isset($cache)) $cache=new cache();
$categories=$cache->get('categories');

function cat_getChildren($id) {
    global $categories;
```

Comment: Hook us up with the code that actually calls the cache class. (line 6 in category.php, plus the surrounding relevant lines)

Comment: if (!isset($cache)) $cache = new cache();

Comment: And two files are included, neither of which define the class.

Comment: Edit your original post and include lines 1-10 from category.php (or all of it if it's not a lot) as well as the code from the two files that are included in category.php @jmooree30

Comment: Id recommend following that include to globals.php to see if/where the `cache` class is supposed to be defined. and/or also see if a package manager should be installing dependencies anywhere (like Composer)

Comment: so the cache class is defined in conn.php, not conn.old.php. Including conn.php cleared the first error and brought upon a new similar error. I think the key to remember here is that it runs on production, and I literally copied the entire directory.

Comment: check all of the production logs to see if anything is being noisy about the cache class not being defined.

Answer (score -2):

it seems that you didn't define the php file that defines the cache class

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer, please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: castis can you tell me please what exactly do you mean ??